# During theme installation theme upload failed

Tags: themes, installation

when tried to upload a theme,got this error.

how can i solve this?
Installing Theme from uploaded file: resume.zip
Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.

can i know why this issue happened?

> Theme installation failed.

Answer (score 3):

The key part from the error is:

> The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.

WordPress docs on [Main Stylesheet](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/) says:

> In order for WordPress to recognize the set of theme template files as a valid theme, the style.css file needs to be located in the root directory of your theme, not a subdirectory.

I would suggest you to unzip the theme and look for `style.css`. If the file is there open it; there should be some commented lines that will look similar to these:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Seventeen
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: Twenty Seventeen brings your site to life with immersive featured images and subtle animations. With a focus on business sites, it features multiple sections on the front page as well as widgets, navigation and social menus, a logo, and more. Personalize its asymmetrical grid with a custom color scheme and showcase your multimedia content with post formats. Our default theme for 2017 works great in many languages, for any abilities, and on any device.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: twentyseventeen
Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-header, accessibility-ready, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, custom-logo, editor-style, featured-images, footer-widgets, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

The following fields should be in every main stylesheet: `Theme Name`, `Author`, `Description`, `Version`, `License`, `License URI` and `Text Domain`.
If any of the mentioned fields are missing I strongly recommend contacting the theme provider.

If you're the owner or the author of the theme make sure to include the mentioned lines and to include the `style.css` file in the root directory of the theme before uploading the archived theme to your WordPress installation.

Also, make sure to read more on Main Stylesheets here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

Answer (score 1):

The theme package is missing an important theme file (**style.css**), which is required.
An anatomy of a WordPress Theme consists of required and recommend files.

See [developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/required-theme-files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/required-theme-files/)  and [codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

This simply means that you should contact the developer(s) of the theme and ask them to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**style.css** file is a required file during wordpress theme installation. Because in your style.css file you have to define your theme related information.

Please refere for more information
[here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/required-theme-files/)

Answer (score 0):

If there is style.css file present and even though you are facing issue then it must be a folder permission issue.
Check with wp-content/themes folder permissions.If you've migrated the website from one server to another server then this folder permission issue comes. Check with hosting provider or server administrator. Or else change the permission to 777.